# How could I understand 'primary' in <Button primary></Button>？

Tags: reactjs

I am using semantic-ui-react in my react app. I just don't know how to understand 'primary' in Button tag. Is this the same as className='primary' or something?

```
render() {
    return (
      <Form>
        <Button primary>Login</Button>
      </Form >
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `primary` is an attribute of the `<Button>` component. In the component, maybe, it might have something like:

```
<button className={"btn" + (this.props.primary ? " btn-primary" : "")}>
  {this.props.children}
</button>
```

You could get more info by looking at the source here: [`Semantic-UI-React/Button.js` at master · Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React · GitHub](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/elements/Button/Button.js).

Comment: Thanks a lot! And primary is actually a prop in the Button Component?